# ModelForm doesn't render TinyMCE (ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined)

Tags: django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I have got django-tinymce working for the admin page. Now outside the admin page, when using a modelform I was expecting the TinyMCE editor to be loaded and shown to the user, this however didn't happen. All I see is a plain text area. But it works in admin page.

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
class Punch(models.Model):
    discussion      = HTMLField()

class PunchForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Punch
```

I can see with firebug that the TinyMCE snippet is added to the HTML:

[image]

However I get an error message in the console:

```
ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

That makes no sense, why does the admin page have no problems finding the TinyMCE?
Besides I added it even myself to the base.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

And the server can load it too:

```
[21/Apr/2013 13:42:40] "GET /static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

SO what could be the problem please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

oh dear, what a silly mistake.

So I can confirm that I have to define the js in `base.html` as I did in my question.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

However this has to be in the header and not the body.  Header is initialized first and hence there won't be any longer a `ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined`

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: saved my ass, i was effin frustrated for the past 2 hours.